# jQuery Show DIV is overflowing other DIVs (footer)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show

I have created a simple show/hide with jQuery. I am having two issues:

1) When I show my hidden DIV, it is appearing over the footer. What I want to happen is for the footer automatically drops down.

2) How can I have the Contact Us DIV open on page load WITHOUT introducing IDs?

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/WkuMg/10/

HTML:

```
<ul class="outline">
    <li>
        <div class="heading"> <a>Contact Us</a>

        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <ul>
                <h1>Contact Us</h1>

                <li>    
                    <a href="">How to reach us</a>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </li>
                <li>    
                    <a href="">How to email us</a>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </li>
                <li>    
                    <a href="">Contact Number</a>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="heading">   
            <a>Products</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <ul>
                <h1>Products</h1>

                <li>    
                    <a href="">Tabels</a>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </li>
                <li>    
                    <a href="">Ladders</a>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </li>
                <li>    
                    <a href="">Chairs</a>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="heading">   
            <a>Our Offices</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <ul>
                <h1>Our offices</h1>

                <li>    
                    <a href="">Bristol</a>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </li>
                <li>    
                    <a href="">Manchester</a>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </li>
                <li>    
                    <a href="">Leeds</a>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".heading").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.next(".content").show(400);
    $this.parent().siblings().children().next().hide();
    return false;
});
```

CSS:

```
.content {
    display: none;
}

.outline {  
    position: relative;
}

.heading {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 20px;
    background: GREY;
    width: 30%;
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 35%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    width: 60%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.footer {
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: @TylerH - CSS added (its also in the fiddle)

Comment: look into http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ @OamPsy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have suggested, your footer issue has to do with your content boxes being absolutely positioned on the page.

I noticed that on your demo/fiddle, you're relying on javascript being enabled or that support for your jQuery library is available. To extend your reach, I created a fallback solution that still works with normal HTML and CSS. The reason you'd want to have a fallback for your content is that maybe your user is on a feature phone, or maybe another JS file threw an exception, causing your content to never be displayed. That all said, the CSS and HTML in the demo below will still work even without JS.

In regards to your demo, you can change the jQuery animations as you see fit. I've also manipulated the HTML you provided. I'm not sure if everything has to stay in your original `ul` list, or if you've got other content you want to put on the page - but based on your filler information, I assumed you had an intention similar to the demo below.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container clearfix">
    <div class="nav">
        <ul class="outline">
            <li><a href="#contact" data-target="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#products" data-target="#products">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#offices" data-target="#offices">Offices</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <div id="contact" class="content">
            <h2>Contact Us</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">How to reach us</a>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">How to email us</a>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact Number</a>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </li>
        </div>
        <div id="products" class="content">
            <h2>Products</h2>
            <p>Purus tortor cras nunc adipiscing cursus ut sociis placerat mattis non montes aliquam aliquet cursus porttitor porta tortor duis porttitor odio. Pid, sit aliquam? Lorem augue eu magnis egestas vut sagittis elit rhoncus massa egestas sociis, in pulvinar a amet, ut adipiscing. Nascetur turpis, turpis pulvinar eu sit.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="offices" class="content">
            <h2>Offices</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>Office 1</li>
                <li>Office 2</li>
                <li>Office 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    Footer
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* let's make sure we clear floated elements so .footer can behave normally */
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; 
    display: table;
}

.clearfix:after { clear: both; }

.nav,
.main { box-sizing: border-box; }

.nav {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 20px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.main {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
}

.footer {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}

/*
  The .hide class is the key here for fallback.
  If JS is not enabled or working the content will show.
  The nav links will also jump to that section. :)
*/
.hide { display: none; }
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.content').addClass('hide');

    $('.outline a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.content').addClass('hide');
        var showContent = $(this).data('target'),
            selector = '.content' + showContent;
        $(selector).removeClass('hide');
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QjTwB/)**

Comment: this make great sense and you have explained clearly. Is there any way that the contents can be accessed through a class rather than an ID?

Comment: Thanks, I can see what you have done by splitting the heading and content in to 2 diffrent DIVs and although that looks fine on a desktop, when viewing on a phone, the content is at the bottom of the headings and not directly below its specific heading... does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, you can manage the show/hide of content containers via a class, but it won't have the fallback support. Keep in mind, that you'd likely use a unique class for each container you're selecting anyways, so an ID makes sense - you can also use `data-*` attributes as well, which I've used in my demo. In your comment about information not stacking makes sense. You can use media queries (or JS) if you'd like to manipulate your CSS or container properties to re-arrange your containers. **[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QjTwB/1/)** with media queries, data-* attributes, and class selectors.

Comment: thanks that makes a lot of sense and you have explained clearly. The issue i am still seeing in your example above, when you reduce the screen size, to call that media query, all content is displayed below the nav items.. When i am trying to get each content item to fit under its corresponding nav item.. Here's a quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/2y6MV/  You can see, under under Contact Us nav item, is the Contact Us content.. Under Products nav item, is the Products content and so on.. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Just trying to gain more sense of what you're trying to accomplish. In your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/2y6MV/) I see that you've created a gray background `div` above each content container. Did you want each of those "headers" to still open/close content, like an accordion? Or are they simply labels to give the page context?

Comment: Hi, i have marked your solution as the answer as it resolves the question i had originally asked. I have raised the second question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864730/setting-height-of-surrounding-div-after-inner-div-is-expanded-collapsed

Answer (score 0):

This is an idea. Do you mind if there footer had a `position:relative;`, thus always leaving room for the content and keeping the footer away from anything. I never seen a footer change locations, they are pretty much away at the bottom anyway,

See [***FIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/WkuMg/12/)

Answer (score 0):

1. set position property for footer and set as bottom.
2. You can set `display: block` using css path.

here the code

```
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
.help-panel {   
position: relative;
}
```

here the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WkuMg/13/)

Answer (score 0):

You might have to change some markup as well as CSS, as i found some invalid HTML in your case, so let's set your left menu together wrapped by a separate `div` and take another `div` as a container!

**HTML Markup**

```
<div class="menu">
<ul class="outline">
    <li>
        <div class="heading"><a>Contact Us</a>
        </div>
    </li>
     <li>
        <div class="heading"><a>Products</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="heading"><a>Our Offices</a>
        </div>
    </li>

</ul>
</div>
<div id="contactus" class="content">
    <ul>
        <h1>Contact Us</h1>
        <li><a href="">How to reach us</a>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </li>
        <li>    <a href="">How to email us</a>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </li>
        <li>    <a href="">Contact Number</a>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="products" class="content">
    <ul>
        <h1>Products</h1>

        <li>    <a href="">Tabels</a>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </li>
        <li>    <a href="">Ladders</a>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </li>
        <li>    <a href="">Chairs</a>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="ouroffices" class="content">
    <ul>
        <h1>Our offices</h1>
        <li><a href="">Bristol</a>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </li>
        <li>    <a href="">Manchester</a>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </li>
        <li>    <a href="">Leeds</a>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".content").first().css("display","inline-block");//To show first one on load
$(".heading").click(function () {    
    $(".content").first().show();
    var $this = $(this);
    var divtoShow = $this.text().toLowerCase().split(" ").join(""); // Removes space between text
    $(".content").hide();
    $("#" + divtoShow).css("display","inline-block"); // Added inline style as on show() they will be display:block by default
    return false;
});
```

*Side Note:* At the time of an implementation keep one thing in mind that **IDs** Must be *unique*,

[**<kbd>Fiddle Example</kbd>**](http://jsfiddle.net/WkuMg/19/)

Comment: Thanks, I can see what you have done by splitting the heading and content in to 2 diffrent DIVs and although that looks fine on a desktop, when viewing on a phone, the content is at the bottom of the headings and not directly below its specific heading... does that make sense?