# Setting height of surrounding DIV after inner DIV is expanded/collapsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple accordion. What i am trying to do is that when an item within the content is clicked (How to reach us) for example, the hidden subsequent text is expanded. Once expanded, the new height of the `content` DIV is calculated. This newly calculated `content` DIV height is then assigned to the height of `.wrapper`. The red wrapper should then surround the entire box.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/jLQf4/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="panel">
        <li>
            <div class="heading">   <a>Menu 1</a>

            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <ul>
                    <h2>Top Ten Questions</h2>
                    <li>    
                        <a href="">How to reach us</a>
                        <p class="hide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">How to email us</a>
                        <p class="hide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Contact Number</a>
                        <p class="hide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.heading {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 20px;
    background: grey;
}
.content {
    background: #99CCFF;
    position: absolute;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}

.wrapper {
    background: #FFD1E0;
    position: relative;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(".content ul li a").click(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.next(".content ul li a").show(400);
  $this.parent().siblings().children().next().hide();
  return false;
});
```

**UPDATE** *************************************************

After the .onClick, would something like:

```
$(".wrappper").css({'height':($(".content").height()+'px')});
```

Work?

**UPDATE** *************************************************

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/jLQf4/9/

Comment: Seems like your selector is wrong here: $this.next(".content ul li a") I removed it in this fiddle and it worked http://jsfiddle.net/jLQf4/2/

Comment: @user2355891 - Thanks.. Any suggestions on the 2nd part of the question - calculating the newly expanded DIV height and assigning it to the .wrapper?

Comment: This what you're after http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jLQf4/4/?

Comment: @j08691 - not necessarily, the content is absolute positioned and cannot be changed (all you have done is remove this).. This is why i am trying to set it via JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, then this may help:

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jLQf4/8/)**

Your `content` div doesn't have a specified width, so it's automatically wrapping whatever is inside of it, when you show your text it extends out further than it was initially.

**EDIT** - I think that there may be an easier way to go about what you're trying to accomplish. Instead of using JS to dynamically update the `.wrapper` I think it would be easier to remove the `position: absolute` from `.content`. Some padding seemed to make it look the same.

CSS:

```
.content {
    width: 280px;
    background: #99CCFF;
    padding: 10px 0;

    //position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. Any suggestions on the 2nd part of the question - calculating the newly expanded DIV height and assigning it to the .wrapper?

Comment: I'm confused, what are you trying to accomplish? the `wrapper` should automatically expand to fit the taller content.

Comment: i know it should, but because it is absolutely positioned, it wont, so i want to set it via jQuery/JavaScript

Comment: i am trying to accomplish setting the height of the .wrapper to the newly expanded height of the content div.

Comment: Okay I think I'm getting what you're after, I'll take a look in a sec.

Comment: i think im nearly there with this: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/jLQf4/7/  getting an [Object Array] alert

Comment: ive created an updated fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/jLQf4/9/, however after i expand an item, the wrapper (red background DIV) is still not showing around the whole contents.

Comment: A simplified piece of JS to set the height of .wrapper to .content would be $(".wrappper").css({'height':($(".content").height()+'px')});

Comment: @OamPsy check my answer's demo fiddle, I think the functionality you're looking for is there.